# potential solutions to create categories in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering if there are better solutions to create a categorical variable based on specified ranges of a numeric column in Pandas.

I have tried using a function or `np.where`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'n': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] }) 

def create_cat(x):
 
    if x < 3:
       return "Low"
    elif x > 3 and x < 6:
       return "Med"
    elif x > 6:
       return "High"

df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: create_cat(x), axis=1)
```

Are there other approaches that might be better than writing a function?

Comment: `pd.cut(df['n'], bins=[3,6], labels=('Low', 'Med', 'High') )`

Comment: @QuangHoang this doesn't work, `ValueError: Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges`

Comment: Side note: your function doesn't actually create an actual `Category` column... just a string column with a value... and you can just call it as `df[col].apply(create_cat)` anyway

Comment: Try: `pd.cut(df['n'], bins=[float('-inf'), 3, 6, float('inf')], labels=['low', 'med', 'high'])` ?